# scp copying from a hard drive through a server

Tags: ssh, server, scp

I want to scp copy some files from a hard drive to my local disk. To ssh to the hard drive, I first have to ssh to a server, then ssh from there on to the hard drive. Normally I'd just copy the files to a location on the server, then scp them to my machine e.g:

```
    scp -r user@server.example.com: ~/folder/ ./
```

The files I want to copy this time are too big to do that. How do I scp directly from the hard drive through the server?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a ssh proxy on the server that tunnels to the hard drive (which has its own ssh server right?)

Check this out:

https://serverfault.com/questions/341190/forward-ssh-through-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 0):

This should be similar to using scp with a server and your local machine, but use the mounted path to/from the hard drive in place of the path to/from your local machine.

```
scp -r user@server.example.com: ~/folder/ /Volumes/NameOfDrive
```